# Passing image back with Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to pass an image back with the rest of my ajax call. I currently am using Facebook Marketing API and I am using foreach() to go through the array's. Everything works fine besides the image. When I try to work it out I get it to display the image_url but, I want the actual image. There is three files home.php where data is displayed (DUH). fbdata.php is where date range data is sent and where the API code is. And finally the third file is the fbdwdrp.php and this is where I have the date range picker and ajax call. All I need to do is figure out how to display the actual image and not the image_url.

```
<?php

        require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
        use FacebookAds\Api;
        use FacebookAds\Object\AdUser;
        use Facebook\Facebook;
        use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
        use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Campaign;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdsInsightsFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Ad;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdSetFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\AdCampaign;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdImageFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
        use FacebookAds\Object\AdSet;
        use FacebookAds\Object\AdCreative;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdCreativeFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdCreativePhotoDataFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\AdCreativeLinkData;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdCreativeLinkDataFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\CampaignFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Page;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdPreviewFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Values\AdPreviewAdFormatValues;
        use FacebookAds\Object\AdVideo;
        ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="background: url(img/main_BG.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;">

  <head>

    <title>Facebook Insights </title>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/imgslidefb.css">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />      
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/daterangepicker.css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.1.25/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.1.25/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datepaginator.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fbdwdrp.js"></script>
    <!-- Include the DateRangeSelector component script. -->
  </head>
<body>
                <div id="demo" style="font: white; float: left; font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif, black; width: 300px; height:65px; background:Grey;">
                    <h4 style="font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif, white; left: 62em; top: 11em;">Select Dates</h4>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    <input type="text" id="config-demo"  style="color: black; background-image: #808080; text-align: center; font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif, black; width: 210px; height:22px;">

                </div></br></br><br/>   
                <?php
                        // Init PHP Sessions
        session_start();

        $fb = new Facebook([
          'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
          'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxx',
        ]);

        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

        if (!isset($_SESSION['xxxxxxx'])) {
          $_SESSION['xxxxxxx'] = null;
        }

        if (!$_SESSION['xxxxxxx']) {
          $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
          try {
            $_SESSION['xxxxxxxxx'] = (string) $helper->getAccessToken();
          } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
            // When Graph returns an error
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
          } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
          }
        }

        if ($_SESSION['xxxxxxxxxx']) {
          //echo "You are logged in!";

        // Initialize a new Session and instantiate an API object
        Api::init(
          'xxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
          'xxxxxxxxxx', //app_secret
          $_SESSION['xxxxxxxx'] // Your user access token
        );

    ?>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Facebook Ads plus past two months.</h1>
            <table class="fbtable">
            <tr class="fbrow">
                <th class="fbheader">Campaign ID</th>
                <th class="fbheader">Campaign Name</th>
                <th class="fbheader">Impressions</th>
                <th class="fbheader">Clicks</th>
                <th class="fbheader">Reach</th>
                <th class="fbheader">Spend</th>
                <th class="fbheader">Total Actions</th>
                <th class="fbheader">CPM</th>
                <th class="fbheader">CPC</th>
                <th class="fbheader">Start Date</th>
                <th class="fbheader">End Date</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="fbrow">
                <td id="1"></td>
                <td id="2"></td>
                <td id="3"></td>
                <td id="4"></td>
                <td id="5"></td>
                <td id="6"></td>
                <td id="7"></td>
                <td id="8"></td>
                <td id="9"></td>
                <td id="10"></td>
                <td id="11"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="fbrow">
                <td id="12"></td>
                <td id="13"></td>
                <td id="14"></td>
                <td id="15"></td>
                <td id="16"></td>
                <td id="17"></td>
                <td id="18"></td>
                <td id="19"></td>
                <td id="20"></td>
                <td id="21"></td>
                <td id="22"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="fbrow">
                <td id="23"></td>
                <td id="24"></td>
                <td id="25"></td>
                <td id="26"></td>
                <td id="27"></td>
                <td id="28"></td>
                <td id="29"></td>
                <td id="30"></td>
                <td id="31"></td>
                <td id="32"></td>
                <td id="33"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="fbrow">
                <td id="34"></td>
                <td id="35"></td>
                <td id="36"></td>
            </tr>
 </table>
 <?php
                }else {
          $permissions = ['ads_management'];
          $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://www.somewebsite.com', $permissions);
          echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook</a>';
        } 
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

*Marketing API CODE*

```
<?php

if((!empty($_POST['startDate'])&&(!empty($_POST['endDate'])))) {    // Check whether the date is empty  



    //setup variables for start and end date..
    $startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['startDate']));
    $endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['endDate']));

    $account = new AdAccount('act_XXXXXXXXX');

        $params = array(
          'time_range' => array(
            'since' => (new \DateTime($startDate))->format('Y-m-d'),
            'until' => (new \DateTime($endDate))->format('Y-m-d'),
          ),
            'thumbnail_width' => 200,
            'thumbnail_height' => 150,
            'level' => 'campaign',
            'limit' => '15'

        );

        $params1 = array(
          'time_range' => array(
            'since' => (new \DateTime("$startDate -1 month"))->format('Y-m-d'),
            'until' => (new \DateTime("$endDate -1 month"))->format('Y-m-d'),
          ),
            'thumbnail_width' => 200,
            'thumbnail_height' => 150,
            'level' => 'campaign',
            'limit' => '15'

        );

        $params2 = array(
          'time_range' => array(
            'since' => (new \DateTime("$startDate -2 month"))->format('Y-m-d'),
            'until' => (new \DateTime("$endDate -2 month"))->format('Y-m-d'),
          ),
            'thumbnail_width' => 200,
            'thumbnail_height' => 150,
            'level' => 'campaign',
            'limit' => '15'

        );

$fields = array(
  AdsInsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_NAME,
  AdsInsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_ID,
  AdsInsightsFields::IMPRESSIONS,
  AdsInsightsFields::CLICKS,
  AdsInsightsFields::REACH,
  AdsInsightsFields::SPEND,
  AdsInsightsFields::CPM,
  AdsInsightsFields::CPC,
  AdsInsightsFields::ACTIONS, 
  AdsInsightsFields::DATE_START,
  AdsInsightsFields::DATE_STOP,
);

$field = array(
  AdCreativeFields::TITLE,
  AdCreativeFields::THUMBNAIL_URL,
  AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_URL,
  AdCreativeFields::BODY,
  );    

$adcreatives = $account->getAdCreatives($field, $params);

$insights = $account->getInsights($fields, $params);
$insights1 = $account->getInsights($fields, $params1);
$insights2 = $account->getInsights($fields, $params2);
 foreach($insights as $i) {

    $impress = number_format((float)$i->impressions);
    $reach = number_format((float)$i->reach);
    $totalAction = number_format((float)$i->actions);
    $cpc = number_format($i->cpc, 2, '.', '');
    $cpm = number_format($i->cpm, 2, '.', '');

    $return['message1'] = $i->campaign_id;
    $return['message2'] = $i->campaign_name;
    $return['message3'] = $impress;
    $return['message4'] = $i->clicks;
    $return['message5'] = $reach;
    $return['message6'] = $i->spend;
    $return['message7'] = $totalAction;
    $return['message8'] = $cpm;
    $return['message9'] = $cpc;
    $return['message10'] = $i->date_start;
    $return['message11'] = $i->date_stop;


}

 foreach($insights1 as $i1) {

    $impress = number_format((float)$i1->impressions);
    $reach = number_format((float)$i1->reach);
    $totalAction = number_format((float)$i1->actions);
    $cpc = number_format($i1->cpc, 2, '.', '');
    $cpm = number_format($i1->cpm, 2, '.', '');

    $return['message12'] = $i1->campaign_id;
    $return['message13'] = $i1->campaign_name;
    $return['message14'] = $impress;
    $return['message15'] = $i1->clicks;
    $return['message16'] = $reach;
    $return['message17'] = $i1->spend;
    $return['message18'] = $totalAction;
    $return['message19'] = $cpm;
    $return['message20'] = $cpc;
    $return['message21'] = $i1->date_start;
    $return['message22'] = $i1->date_stop;

}

 foreach($insights2 as $i2) {

    $impress = number_format((float)$i2->impressions);
    $reach = number_format((float)$i2->reach);
    $totalAction = number_format((float)$i2->actions);
    $cpc = number_format($i2->cpc, 2, '.', '');
    $cpm = number_format($i2->cpm, 2, '.', '');

    $return['message23'] = $i2->campaign_id;
    $return['message24'] = $i2->campaign_name;
    $return['message25'] = $impress;
    $return['message26'] = $i2->clicks;
    $return['message27'] = $reach;
    $return['message28'] = $i2->spend;
    $return['message29'] = $totalAction;
    $return['message30'] = $cpm;
    $return['message31'] = $cpc;
    $return['message32'] = $i2->date_start;
    $return['message33'] = $i2->date_stop;

}

foreach($adcreatives as $imgs){

     $return['message34'] = $imgs->title;
     $return['message35'] = $imgs->image_url;
     $return['message36'] = $imgs->body;

}

            header('Content-Type: text/json');              
            echo json_encode($return); //echo response back to Home page... 
}
}
?>
```

*AJAX CALL AND DATE RANGE PICKER FILE*

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#config-demo').click(function() {
              $(this).parent().find('#demo').click();
            });
            updateConfig();

            function updateConfig() {

                    var start = moment().subtract(2, 'month');
                    var end = moment();

              var options = {

                   "showDropdowns": true,
              };
              options.opens = "center";

            options.ranges = {
                  'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                  'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                  'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                  'Last 14 Days': [moment().subtract(13, 'days'), moment()],
                  'Last 28 Days': [moment().subtract(27, 'days'), moment()],
                  'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                  'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            };

              $('#config-demo').daterangepicker(options, function(start, end, label) { 
                    var startDate = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
                    var endDate = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    passDate(startDate, endDate);

               });
            }
    });

    function passDate(startDate,endDate) {
        $('.loader').show();
        $.ajax({
                method: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use
                url: 'fbdata.php', // the url where we want to POST
                dataType: 'json', // Our data object
                data: {startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate}, // Ensure we pass the start and end dates to $_POST in PHP
            })

            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('.loader').hide();
                alert("OOOOO");
                $('#1').text(data.message1); // log data to the console so we can see
                $('#2').text(data.message2); // log data to the console so we can see
                $('#3').text(data.message3); // log data to the console so we can see
                $('#4').text(data.message4); // log data to the console so we can see
                $('#5').text(data.message5); // log data to the console so we can see
                $('#6').text(data.message6); // log data to the console so we can see
                $('#7').text(data.message7); // log data to the console so we can see
                $('#8').text(data.message8); // log data to the console so we can see
                $('#9').text(data.message9); // log data to the console so we can see
                $('#10').text(data.message10); // log data to the console so we can see
                $('#11').text(data.message11); // log data to the console so we can see
                $('#34').text(data.message34); // log data to the console so we can see
                $('#35').append('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data.message35 + '" />'); // log data to the console so we can see
                $('#36').text(data.message36); // log data to the console so we can see
```

Comment: Figured it out.  I was not adding this code below into the ajax call back.                 $('#35').html('<img src="' + data.message35 + '" />');

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this in the AJAX call File. in the .done(function(data){} area.

```
$('#35').html('<img src="' + data.message35 + '" />'); // log data to the console so we can see
```